# rails scope order by atribute of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Let's say I have a class Foo which belongs_to :bar.

Bar has an attribute name. I want to create a scope that orders Foos by bar.name. How do I do that with scope?

Like,
scope :by_name, order('')?

I am very new to rails so I am sorry if this question does not make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this...

```
scope :by_bar_name, order('bars.name').includes(:bar)
```

Comment: .joins(:bar) instead of includes is also an option

Answer (score 0):

Or less memory intensive:

`scope :by_bar_name, joins(:bar).order('bars.name')`